# google sheet split string with regex

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a string like this one:

`Vegano-CO0056, Fagottino-FA0028, Mandorle-CB0025, Frolle-B108`

it could be longer or shorter.
I need to extract all the codes between "-" and "," (except the last one which doesn't end with a comma). All the codes should be then inserted in a preformatted string like this one

"Hello, the product you ordered are: 1 CO0056, 1 FA0028, 1 CB0025, 1 B108. Thank you"

thanks

So far I tried these formula whcih both display ERROR in their cell:
`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"-[.*?],")`
`=IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,":-([^\(]+,")))`

Comment: This is not just about extraction (I guess you want to count each code, right?) so just a regex won't help. It is easier done with a script. The pattern is `-([^,]+)`, then you'd grab Group 1 value, but `REGEXEXTRACT` only returns the first match.

Comment: First off brackets `[]` match literal characters contained within, so `[.*?]` matches a period, star, or question mark. A regex to match the segments of your strings is this `-(.*?)(,|$)`. Whether or not this is a good way to solve the issue or not is a separate issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no need to count the code. just extract the codes and add them to the other string

Comment: @Mako212 this returns formula error `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"-(.*?)(,|$)")`

Comment: so the input string always has only the *unique* product codes; I mean like no chance of there being a scenario as such: `product you ordered are: 2 CO0056.`

Comment: The regex must be `-([^,]+)` or `-([^ ,]+)`, but it will still not help since `REGEXEXTRACT` returns the first match. You need a whole script here.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option. It splits by ", ", and then applies REGEXEXTRACT to get the codes. With QUERY in the second step finds the count of each element, then in the third line it joins with a space the count and the code; and finally it creates the last string:

```
=LET(all,INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(TOCOL(SPLIT(A1,", "),1),"-(.+)")),
counted,QUERY(all,"SELECT COUNT(Col1),Col1 GROUP BY Col1 LABEL COUNT(Col1) ''"),
prod_string,BYROW(counted,LAMBDA(s, JOIN(" ",s))),
"You ordered "&JOIN(", ",prod_string)&". Thank you")
```

[image]

Comment: ok this works besides I didn't need the count (each code is always 1 amout). thank you